# Rename file in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I want to rename existing files in Laravel .. like I have items table and every item has picture .. and when I rename the item I mean update the item .. 
I want to rename the image as well ..

This is my code ..

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $color = Color::find($id);
  $old_value = $color->color_name;

  if($request->ajax())
  {
    $check = Color::where('color_name','=',$request->color_name)->count();

    if($check == 1 and $request->color_name <> $old_value)
    {
      return response()->json([
        'error'=>'same',
        'old_value'=>$old_value,
      ]);
    }
    else
    {   
      $color->color_name = $request->color_name;
      $color->save();   
      $file = base_path()."/public/upload/colors/1/$old_value.jpg";

      /* here where i want to rename the variabel file to the new name com from the request */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Official Documentation for your needs

```
Storage::move('old/file1.jpg', 'new/file1.jpg');
```

I think you might be able to change the file name when you use move method

[Filesystem/Cloud Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#storing-files)